# How to make my image and desc responsive so that it changes how it looks in desktop and mobile?

Tags: html, css

How do I make my image and description responsive so that it changes from what I currently have on desktop?

Desktop:
[image: desktop]

Mobile:

[image: mobile]

Here's my HTML and CSS:

```css
.restaurant-card {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0 40px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  background-color: maroon;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.restaurant-card img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.restaurant-title {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: x-large;
  margin-right: 400px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

.restaurant-description {
  font-size: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-family: "Domine", serif;
}

a:hover span {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #FFEB88;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="restaurant-card">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="Images\lou-wong.jpg" width="500" height="300" />
  </a>
  <div>
    <a href="#" style="color: white">
      <span>
        <p class="restaurant-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;Ipoh Lou Wong</p>
        <p class="restaurant-description">The 61-year old restaurant serves only checken rice and
            bean
            sprouts fried in Ipoh, Malaysia. Lou Wong Restauraunt (Restoran Tauge Ayam Lou Wong, Lou
            Wong
            Opoh, Loud Wong Chicken Resturaunt) is one of the most attractive popular tourist places
            in the
            center of Opoh old town. It has to be the MOST famous of all Ipoh's restaunts, bar none.
        </p>
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like in the dev tool:

[image: dev tool].

I'm thinking that I'm supposed to use some sort of grid to make row and columns but I have no idea how it would make the image on left and description on right for the desktop to image on top and description on the bottom for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use @media in the css file.
Here you go some references:
[W3Schools @media Rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.php) and
[MDN: @media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media). Also using `display: flex;` + `flex-direction: column;` could also help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).